# Selenium web driver - check box not getting clicked

Tags: selenium

I tried to click on a check box in the link http://www.deal4loans.com/agent.php  .But it is not getting checked .Below is my code .For the chcek boxes to appear we need to select  2 nd option from the I am drop down

But I have noticed that if the code is written only to check these check boxes without adding data for all other fields except the check boxes it works .But when we enter data for Name,mail id,Iam  ,city,mobile  then the Product you deal will not work .

Please help

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
public class Test {
    public static WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        driver.get("http://www.deal4loans.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[1]/a[1]")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);     
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("Vish");
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("vish@gmail.com");

        Select listbox1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/select")));
         listbox1.selectByValue("2");
       Select listbox2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/select")));
          listbox2.selectByValue("Chennai");

          driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[2]/input")).sendKeys("9898765676");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Personal Loan']")).click(); 

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Home Loan']")).click(); 

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Car Loan']")).click(); 

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Loan Against Property']")).click(); 

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Business Loan']")).click();

            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Credit Card']")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div/div[4]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/table/tbody/tr[9]/td/input")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     }


     }
```

Comment: Can you please try ID instead of Xpath for checkbox? It will work with ID.

Answer (score 2):

**Got the issue!!**

There are **2 divs, div with id 'div0' and div with 'div1', with 'display attribute' changing from 'none' to 'block' and they have the same checkboxes with same 'value' attribute**, and hence they weren't getting clicked. Below is the image for that Checkbox block:

[image]

Below code will work all times, (o'course when the options are displayed). I have also modified your code with relative xpaths for consistency:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

driver.get("http://www.deal4loans.com/");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[.='Agents Login']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.name("From_Name")).sendKeys("Vish");
driver.findElement(By.name("From_Email")).sendKeys("vish@gmail.com");

Select listbox1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("query_type")));
listbox1.selectByValue("2");
Select listbox2 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("city")));
listbox2.selectByValue("Chennai");

driver.findElement(By.name("Mobile")).sendKeys("9898765676");

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@style,'block')]//input[@value='Personal Loan']")).click(); 

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@style,'block')]//input[@value='Home Loan']")).click(); 

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@style,'block')]//input[@value='Car Loan']")).click(); 

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@style,'block')]//input[@value='Loan Against Property']")).click(); 

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@style,'block')]//input[@value='Business Loan']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@style,'block')]//input[@value='Credit Card']")).click();

driver.findElement(By.name("submit")).click();
```

Comment: @RupeshShinde : Gee..Thanks.. :) I am sure if it works out for Poster too, she will surely mark it as answer.. :)